How can vi write a file without permissions?
I created a file using touch test, then changed the file permission using chmod 000 test, then did vi test, wrote random characters, I was successfully able to save the file using :wq!. I'm the owner of the file but how am I able to write after changing the permissions of the file to 000?

If I'm not mistaking, chmod 000 <file> makes a file impossible to read, write or execute. If that would succeed, then how do you expect being able to do anything with that file?

That's exactly my question bro. The file permissions is 000. I expect the behaviour that vi should not allow me to write, but it is allowing. It just shows the warning "W10: Warning: Changing a readonly file".

Yes, I'm really using the vi editor to edit my file.

You took away your file's permissions, you can also restore them.
None of this is carved in stone.
You're explicitly asking Vim to do it for you by adding a bang to the :wq command, see :help :wq.
In fact, the whole point of the bang is to say I don't care, just write that file.
Which is also what :help W10 is about.
It's just a warning that you did just change a write protected file.
You can easily test this by running Vim through strace.
As a test, I ran
touch test
chmod 000 test
strace vim -N -u NONE test 2> traces

I got the following results (with annotations):
chmod("test", 0100200)                  = 0              <-- give write permission
< snip >
openat(AT_FDCWD, "test", O_WRONLY|O_CREAT, 0200) = 6
fstat(6, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0200, st_size=11, ...}) = 0
ftruncate(6, 0)                         = 0
write(6, "foobar\n", 7)                 = 7              <-- write "foobar"
fsync(6)                                = 0
fchmod(6, 0100000)                      = 0              <-- remove permission again
close(6)                                = 0              <-- close file

This is the same as entering the following commands:
chmod 200 test
echo foobar > test
chmod 000 test

Things would be different if the file did not belong to you and was created, e.g. by root.
In this case, Vim (or any other program) would be powerless.
If you open a write-protected file, you'll notice the readonly option is set in Vim.
It will be reset after you make a change and W10 was displayed.
To completely prevent any changes to a buffer, you can :set nomodifiable.
You won't be able to change text unless you reset the option again.
PS: I'm answering for Vim, not vi, because 1) I don't have vi installed, and 2) most systems have vi aliased to vim, and 3) although the implementation will be different, it would work the same on vi.
